How to intercept HLS segment requests in iOS AVPlayer
I'm trying to intercept HLS segment requests made by AVPlayer in iOS for the purpose of decryption, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
I've tried two different approaches:

AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate: This only intercepts the m3u8 files.
CustomURLProtocol: This isn't working at all for me but the thought was to intercept the .m4s segment requests.

I know that the AVPlayer is making the call to get the .m4s segment files because I can see these requests in my network logs, but I'm unable to intercept them using either the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate or the CustomURLProtocol methods.
Here's my current implementation:
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

class CustomURLProtocol: URLProtocol {
    static var requestHandler: ((URLRequest) -> (URLResponse?, Data?, Error?))?

    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        // Intercept only HLS segment requests
        print("CustomURLProtocol canInit called for URL: \(request.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
        return request.url?.pathExtension == "m4s"
    }

    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        return request
    }

    override func startLoading() {
        guard let handler = CustomURLProtocol.requestHandler else {
            return
        }

        let (response, data, error) = handler(request)

        if let response = response {
            client?.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .notAllowed)
        }

        if let data = data {
            client?.urlProtocol(self, didLoad: data)
        }

        if let error = error {
            client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
        }

        client?.urlProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
    }

    override func stopLoading() {
        // This method is called if the request gets canceled or completed
    }
}

class CustomResourceLoaderDelegate: NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {
    func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
        // This only processes the m3u8 playlists. We know this because we don't allow it to process m4s and the video still plays

        // NOTE: HLS SEGMENTS DO NOT GO THROUGH HERE AS THE AVPLAYER HANDLES THEM

        // Ensure we have a URL to work with
        guard let url = loadingRequest.request.url else {
            return false
        }

        print("CustomResourceLoaderDelegate: \(url)")

        // For all other files, implement the redirect logic
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
        components?.scheme = "https"

        guard let httpsURL = components?.url else {
            return false
        }

        // Create a redirect response
        let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: url, statusCode: 302, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: ["Location": httpsURL.absoluteString])

        // Set the response on the loading request
        loadingRequest.response = response
        loadingRequest.finishLoading()

        return true
    }
}

struct VideoSecurityDemo: View {
    private let player: AVPlayer
    private let resourceLoaderDelegate = CustomResourceLoaderDelegate()

    init() {
        // Register the CustomURLProtocol
        URLProtocol.registerClass(CustomURLProtocol.self)

        // Set up the request handler
        CustomURLProtocol.requestHandler = { request in
            print("Intercepted HLS segment request: \(request.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")

            // Perform the actual request
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            var responseData: Data?
            var responseError: Error?
            var responseURL: URLResponse?

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                responseData = data
                responseError = error
                responseURL = response
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            task.resume()

            _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)

            return (responseURL, responseData, responseError)
        }

        let urlString = "customscheme://mywebsite.com/file.m3u8"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(resourceLoaderDelegate, queue: .main)

        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear {
                print("VideoPlayer appeared, starting playback")
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                print("VideoPlayer disappeared, pausing playback")
                player.pause()
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    VideoSecurityDemo()
}

I wish there was a solution similar to the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate. I am hoping that there is something that I missed. The next thing I am going to try is a local HTTP server approach.
Thanks!
